# How to replace multiple strings starting with the same pattern on the same line

Tags: string, sed, replace

The input I have is:

> blabla  0/1:0,1,0:1 1/1:0,0,1.000:2   0/0:1,0,0:0
>   1/0:0,0.943,0.057:1.057 blabla

The output I want is:

> blabla  RA  AA    RR RA blabla

Each entry/string is separated by tab. And all the entries/strings are on the same line. 

I am only showing four entries above as an example, there are hundreds of other entries there with similar patterns I am looking for. That is each string begins with 0/1, 1/0, 1/0, or 1/1.

I want to replace the string starting with `0/1` or `1/0` to `RA`, the string starting with `0/0` to `RR`, and the string starting with `1/1` to `AA`.

The code I am using right now is

```
echo blabla  0/1:0,1,0:1 1/1:0,0,1.000:2    0/0:1,0,0:0 1/0:0,0.943,0.057:1.057 blabla | sed -e "s/0\/0/RR/g" -e "s/0\/1/RA/g" -e "s/1\/0/RA/g" -e "s/1\/1/AA/g"
```

However, the output is

```
blabla RA:0,1,0:1 AA:0,0,1.000:2 RR:1,0,0:0 RA:0,0.943,0.057:1.057 blabla
```

I also tried the following code

```
echo blabla  0/1:0,1,0:1 1/1:0,0,1.000:20/0:1,0,0:0 1/0:0,0.943,0.057:1.057 blabla | sed -e "s/0\/0:.*\\t/RR\\t/g" -e "s/0\/1:.*:\\t/RA\\t/g" -e "s/1\/0:.*\\t/RA\\t/g" -e "s/1\/1:.*\\t/AA\\t/g"
```

It seems not working at all.

Comment: Oops, You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. 
Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: You say you want to replace `0/1` or `1/0` with `RA`, but it appears that you have replaced `0/1:0,1,0:1` with `RA`.  Are you saying that you want any string consisting of any non-whitespace characters that begins with `0/1` or `1/0` to be replaced with `RA`, or are you only interested in strings matching `0/1[:01,]*` or `1/0[:01,]*`?  What if `blabla` is `0/1text:0:1`? What will you do with `2/1:0,1`?  The question is ill specified.

Comment: I included my code there, sorry for the misunderstanding. I want any string consisting of any non-whitespace characters that begins with 0/1 or 1/0 to be replaced with RA, begins with 0/0 to be replaced with RR, begins with 1/1 to be replaced with AA. All the strings begin with 0/1, 1/0, 0/0, or 1/1.@WilliamPursell

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
echo blabla  0/1:0,1,0:1 1/1:0,0,1.000:2    0/0:1,0,0:0 1/0:0,0.943,0.057:1.057 blabla | sed -E "s/0\/1[^ \t]+/RA/g; s/1\/0[^ \t]+/RA/g; s/0\/0[^ \t]+/RR/g; s/1\/1[^ \t]+/AA/g"
```

Which yields:

> blabla RA AA RR RA blabla

**Explanation:**

Let's focus on a single replacement: `s/0\/1[^ \t]+/RA/g`

This replaces `0\1anyth1ngexceptwhitespaces` with `RA`.

Repeat 3 times for the other 3 patterns.

For newer versions of `sed` you can replace `"<space>\t"` with `"\s"`

Comment: Thank you! This works if each entry/string is separated by space. However, it seems not working when each entry/string is separated by tab. The output I get is     blabla RA                                                                                        if they are separated by tab. @Jedi

Comment: That works! Since I am running the code with macOS Sierra, I replaced '\t' with '${printf '\t'}'. Thank you@Jedi.

Comment: @fsns In your case, I'd try `[^[:space:]]` instead of `[^ \t]`.